# Cannot use asterisk as glob pattern normally in Snakemake

Tags: python, shell, glob, snakemake

I want to use asterisk as glob pattern to stand for "any string of characters except /" (as stated in [glob Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))) in Snakemake rule file in its `shell` section. But noticed that I cannot use it normally as in Shell terminal. Am I making any mistake in my rule file, or is it because Snakemake has forbidden it in the latest version?

My rule file looks like:

```
barcodes = ["AAA", "GGG", "TTT"]

rule end:
    input: "output/merged.txt"

rule test_glob:
    input: "per_barcode/sample_*_rep_{barcode}.txt"
    output: "output/{barcode}.txt"
    shell:
        "head {input} > {output}"

rule merge:
    input: expand("output/{barcode}.txt", barcode = barcodes)
    output: "output/merged.txt"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

And the files are:

```
ls per_barcode/
sample_10_rep_GGG.txt  sample_2_rep_AAA.txt  sample_5_rep_TTT.txt
```

And the error message is:

```
MissingInputException in line 7 of test.smk:
Missing input files for rule test_regex:
per_barcode/sample_*_rep_GGG.txt
```

But if I change the rule `test_glob` to the following to use the glob pattern in `shell` command instead of in `input`, it works:

```
rule test_glob:
    output: "output/{barcode}.txt"
    shell:
        "head per_barcode/sample_*_rep_{wildcards.barcode}.txt > {output}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with a general asterisk glob in snakemake due to the execution paradigm.  An asterisk says "give me all files that are present here", but snakemake requires knowing what those files are so it can generate them (if needed).  In your second example, while it runs it fails to inform snakemake what the input files actually are.  If you modify a a sample file, snakemake will be unable to detect and rerun the rule.  The better way to write it is with an input function:

```
barcodes = ["AAA", "GGG", "TTT"]

rule end:
    input: "output/merged.txt"

def test_glob_input(wildcards):
    # get list of samples, format name with barcode from wildcards
    samples = glob_wildcards(
                 f"per_barcode/sample_{{sample}}_rep_{wildcards.barcode}.txt"
              ).sample
    return expand(
           "per_barcode/sample_{sample}_rep_{barcode}.txt",
           sample=samples,
           barcode=wildcards.barcode)


rule test_glob:
    input: test_glob_input
    output: "output/{barcode}.txt"
    shell:
        "head {input} > {output}"

rule merge:
    input: expand("output/{barcode}.txt", barcode = barcodes)
    output: "output/merged.txt"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Now if a file changes, snakemake will rerun dependent outputs.  However, if you have to generate those sample files first, this will *fail* because it just looks at what is currently on the file system.  This may not be an issue, but the best method is to have a config, json, or csv file that can map each sample to a barcode.  Then your input function can pull from that to determine which samples it needs.

```
barcodes = ["AAA", "GGG", "TTT"]
# need a dictionary or dataframe with barcode to sample mapping
barcodes_to_sample = {"AAA": ['a1', 'a2', a3'], "GGG": ['g1', 'g2'], ...}

rule end:
    input: "output/merged.txt"

def test_glob_input(wildcards):
    # get list of samples from wildcard information
    samples = barcodes_to_sample[wildcards.barcode]
    return expand(
           "per_barcode/sample_{sample}_rep_{barcode}.txt",
           sample=samples,
           barcode=wildcards.barcode)


rule test_glob:
    input: test_glob_input
    output: "output/{barcode}.txt"
    shell:
        "head {input} > {output}"

rule merge:
    input: expand("output/{barcode}.txt", barcode = barcodes)
    output: "output/merged.txt"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

While this subtly changes the file, the effect on execution means you can add upstream rules to say download or filter a file and still have everything work.

I'm not sure snakemake ever allowed glob asterisk in an input rule, AFAIK.